# Neo4j how to orderBy collection

Tags: neo4j

I have node structure where i have parent nodes and child nodes. Child nodes have :has relation ship with parent node.

My current query is

```
 Match (p:Parent)
 Where Id(p) = 2
 WITH p
 Match (c:CHILD)
 WHERE (p)-[:has]-(c)
 return p,collect(DISTINCT c) as child[0..9]
```

Now my problem is all child nodes are arranged by their id's and i am only able to receive first 9 childs ordered by their id.

**How can i specify order of childs?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

You can use an in-between WITH to order your nodes.
Btw. you should have consistent label spelling!

```
 Match (p:Parent)-[:has]-(c:CHILD)
 Where Id(p) = 2
 WITH p, c order by id(c) asc
 return p,collect(DISTINCT c)[0..9] as child
```